# tinymce uncaught TypeError: Theme is not a constructor(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-4

My following react component show following error with tinymce and did not mount in dom.

**theme.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

**tinymce.js:38447 Uncaught TypeError: Theme is not a constructor(…)**

```
import React from "react";
import tinymce from "tinymce";

const ParagraphDetails = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount(){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: ".tinymce-editor",
            themes: "modern",
        })
    },
    render(){
        return <div>
            <label>About
                <textarea rows="3" className="tinymce-editor"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
    }
});
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with directory structure tinymce. As per issue It does not support the webpack.

[Here's](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2836) the solution on github issues.

You need tinymce and a couple of loaders for webpack.

```
npm i --save tinymce
npm i --save-dev imports-loader exports-loader
```

**Webpack config**

```
const config = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('tinymce/tinymce'),
        loaders: [
          'imports?this=>window',
          'exports?window.tinymce'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /tinymce\/(themes|plugins)\//,
        loaders: [
          'imports?this=>window'
        ]
      }    
    ]
  }
}
```

**Implementation** in a file

```
// Core - these two are required :-)
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce'
import 'tinymce/themes/modern/theme'

// Plugins
import 'tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/link/plugin'
import 'tinymce/plugins/autoresize/plugin'

// Initialize
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#tinymce',
  skin: false,
  plugins: ['paste', 'link', 'autoresize']
})
```

Comment: Can you suggest me the same for angularjs

Comment: So this answer is accepted, but wasn't upvoted... I don't get it really... Solution works for JS files. Worth adding that we should use `skin: false` and load CSS manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize tinymce in componentDidMount , and not in componentWillMount.
Also, you need to export 'ParagraphDetails' class.

Comment: All things working right except tinymce. I also try with componentDidMount but it gives same error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code is not pure `JS`, It's `JSX`. (JavaScript Extension)

> theme.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This error is because of `JSX`. You need to convert `JSX` to `JS` since browser don't have knowledge of `JSX`.

In order to do this you need to use [babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) plugin

> tinymce.js:38447 Uncaught TypeError: Theme is not a constructor(…)

You can't initialize your library without `DOM` element, So initialize your library after `component` gets mounted.

Instead of this

```
componentWillMount(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".tinymce-editor", //you don't have this element as of now
        themes: "modern",
    })
},
```

Try this

```
componentDidMount(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".tinymce-editor", //you'll have this element in DOM
        themes: "modern",
    })
},
```

Comment: it's only a problem with tinymce, rather it working exactly the way i want. I used webpack and babel loader presets:  'es2015', "react", "stage-1"

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-tinymce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tinymce) component if you are using in react.

Comment: have you put tinymce.js file in your main index.html file inside head ? because react-tinymce depends on [tinymce.js](https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js),